# How to exactly match the result of cumulative distribution function and quantile function?

Tags: r, matlab, statistics

As we know, `quantile` function is the inverse cumulative distribution function.

Then for an existed distribute(a vector), how to exactly match the result of `cumulative distribution function` and `quantile` function?

Here is an example given in MATLAB.

```
a = [150   154   151   153   124]
[x_count, x_val] = hist(a, unique(a));
% compute the probability cumulative distribution 
p = cumsum(n)/sum(n);
x_out = quantile(a, p)
```

In the cumulative distribution function, the corresponding relation between  cumulative probability and x value should be:

```
x = 124   150   151   153   154
p = 0.2000    0.4000    0.6000    0.8000    1.0000
```

But use *p* and *quantile* to compute *x_out*, the result is different with *x*:

```
x_out =

  137.0000  150.5000  152.0000  153.5000  154.0000
```

**Reference**

1. [quantile function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function)
2. [matlab quantile function](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/stats/quantile.html#responsive_offcanvas)

Comment: The documentation for the R function is much better: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/quantile.html

Comment: Please add an explanation of how you got to your desired output (i.e. why you think your Matlab code is wrong).

Comment: @Dan, I expect the two functions have exactly mapped x-y pairs.

Comment: @ouxiaogu but why do you expect that? You have not explicitly defined *your* algorithm for finding quantiles. Matlab has defined theirs and even uses your exact use case as the example in the docs. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32066046/1011724) for more.

Comment: @Dan, I see. I don't look matlab's quantile algorithm very carefully. I just from the view of inverse function to understand quantile x.

Comment: From math perspective it is undefined, because the function you are inverting has a step in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/quantile.html#btf91zm):

> For a data vector of five elements such as {6, 3, 2, 10, 1}, the sorted elements {1, 2, 3, 6, 10} respectively correspond to the 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9 quantiles.

So if you wanted to get the exact numbers out that you put in for `x`, and your `x` has 5 elements then your `p` needs to be `p = [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9]`. The complete algorithm is explicitly defined in the documentation.

You have assumed that to get `x` back, `p` should have been `[0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1]`. But then why not `p = [0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8]`? Matlab's algorithm seems to just take a linear average of the two methods.

Note that [R defines](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/quantile.html) ***nine*** different algorithms for quantiles, so your assumptions need to be stated clearly.